# GA Headsets - is there a standard for the replaceable microphone?

Tags: general-aviation, headset

I've noticed that on many (but not all) different types of GA headset, the microphone seems to be somewhat modular, with two holes at the end for the microphone boom to insert into, and two screws at the front that seem to be able to be used to both hold it in place on the boom, and also fasten the two parts of the plastic microphone assembly in place.

**Example microphone modules:**
 [image: Example microphone #1] [image: Example microphone #2] [image: Example Microphone #3]

Is there some standard for microphone modules, or is what I'm noticing just coincidence?

Background: One of my headset microphones no longer works due to being ... unintentionally regurgitated upon - I'm wondering whether I can just buy one that looks similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a coincidence, the connection is a modular microphone standard called U-172/U. The pins it connects to are the U-173/U standard.

You can't just get any microphone that has that connector though, it's not aviation specific. You need to get a microphone which has the right impedance and is designed to work with the voltage on an aircraft communication system. There's plenty of options, some which give better noise cancelling properties than others.

All you need to do is get the parameters of your hurl-covered one and get one with the same parameters.

There's information on aviation connectors and standards [here](http://www.acousticom.com/2015/aviation-headset-information-specs/), and [here](http://mouser.com/ds/2/18/Nexus_Catalog-537765.pdf).

Comment: Do you have a reference (link) to the standard? I couldn't find anything but links for purchase.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of standard you want but you can get measurements for all sorts of audio connectors on the mouser electronics site. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/18/Nexus_Catalog-537765.pdf. See my edit for more.

Comment: Standard in the sense of the specification as defined by its creators (or maintainers), such as IPsec is defined here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4309 by IETF... Those docs are good, though. Thanks.